# Prevent Deadlocks in Vendor Databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock

We have a Windows Update (WSUS) database that is used by Windows Update (obviously). A couple of times a day we will receive deadlocks on this database caused by the WSUS application running 2 update queries on the same record. The 2 queries come from the same process on one server.

We have tried changing the database to read committed snapshot, however that hasn't improved the situation. The WSUS process isn't reporting any errors, and the sys admin team is happy with how it's running.

Is there anything we should do to try and fix this, or should we just ignore the alerts for deadlocks on that database?

---

UPDATE: Deadlock has happened again. See below for the graph details:
[image: deadlock graph]

For some reason stack exchange won't let me post the xml here.

Comment: Snapshot Isolation will help when readers are blocking a writer.  It will not help when 2 writes are blocking each other.

Comment: Yep realise that. Was hoping that maybe it had a select that was blocking the update and the update blocking the select when the deadlock hit and so changing the isolation level might prevent the select from being blocked.

Comment: Maybe add the deadlock graph.

Comment: If the deadlock is caused purely by the Windows Update app, suggest capturing the details in the log with TF1222 enabled and filing a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com so the rightful owners of the app can deal with it. While unlikely to cause serious issues, if they increase significantly in frequency, it may result in longer patch window and busier server/storage (rollbacks aren't free). Low chance of happening but not zero.

Comment: It's no longer in the system_health XE. Since posing the question there hasn't been any deadlocks - always the way right? As per https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/extended-events-doesnt-hard/ I've setup XE to capture deadlocks for next time. Will update the question when I have answers

Answer (score 2):

As you are on SQL Server 2014, you can simply harvest historical deadlocks from the `system_health` Extended Events (XE) session and do some analysis.  It should be running all the time and will contain deadlocks since that last SQL Server service restart, although the `ring_buffer` *could* have cycled and ejected some older records.  Try code from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31280.finding-and-extracting-deadlock-information-using-extended-events.aspx) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2013/04/27/an-in-depth-look-at-sql-server-memory-part-2.aspx).  This 
No need for Trace flag `1222` and no need to run Profiler / server side trace with the Deadlock Graph event which can only capture deadlocks from the time you start them / turn the trace flag on.  You can just look back in time.

As the WSUS database is relatively public domain (and not your secret business logic database) you could publish some of the deadlock XML here and we can help with the investigation.  Deadlocks are sometimes due to missing indexes, or if there are excessive exchange events then might be down to parallelism.  Let's have a look!